# new typeof(abstract class)

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I've got abstract class **Item** and some child polymorphic classes of Item like: **Sword**, **Axe** etc.

Is it possible in c++ to do something like:

```
Item* firstVariable = new Sword();
Item* secondVariable = new typeof(firstVariable);
```

When I do like this I've got an error that Item is an abstract class.
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Implement a virtual clone function. And it's hard to see how you got the error you say you did, as C++  doesn't have a typeof operator.

Comment: @NeilButterworth `typeof` is a gcc language extension which predates `decltype` and also works in C mode. It is made available if no "-std=" (or "-ansi") argument is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain Neil's comment, here's what the basic clone idiom, or virtual copy idiom, looks like:

```
class Item {
public:
    virtual ~Item() = 0;
    virtual Item* clone() const = 0;
protected:
    Item(const Item&) = default;
    Item(Item&&) = default;
    Item& operator=(const Item&) = default;
    Item& operator=(Item&&) = default;
};

Item::~Item() = default;

class Sword : public Item {
public:
    virtual Item* clone() const override
    { return new Sword(*this); }
};

class Axe : public Item {
public:
    virtual Item* clone() const override
    { return new Axe(*this); }
};

int main()
{
    Item* firstVariable = new Sword();
    Item* secondVariable = firstVariable->clone();
    delete firstVariable;
    delete secondVariable;
}
```

However, I recommend practically never using `new` and `delete`, since they make it too easy to make mistakes that land you with dangling pointers, doubled deletes, memory leaks, exception-unfriendly code, and so on.  Here's a safer solution:

```
#include <memory>

class Item {
public:
    virtual ~Item() = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Item> clone() const = 0;
protected:
    Item(const Item&) = default;
    Item(Item&&) = default;
    Item& operator=(const Item&) = default;
    Item& operator=(Item&&) = default;
};

Item::~Item() = default;

class Sword : public Item {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Item> clone() const override
    { return std::make_unique<Sword>(*this); }
};

class Axe: public Item {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Item> clone() const override
    { return std::make_unique<Axe>(*this); }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Item> firstVariable = std::make_unique<Sword>();
    std::unique_ptr<Item> secondVariable = firstVariable->clone();
}
```